# Trouble linking css and js files in html head

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been studying Web Development for the past couple months and have consistently had trouble with linking to both local and global files in html. I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing, usually when I'm experimenting with bootstrap for example I will simply go on bootstraps site and copy the links from their getting started page. For whatever reason the css will link fine but the js file will not. To test the functionality I just copy some of their code examples and paste them and the styling works fine but the js functionally doesn't. That's just one example of something I have been dealing with since I started Web Development. It's very discouraging to literally copy and paste links like that and have it not work. I feel like I could be making some simple mistake but I'm just not sure. I'm always careful to include the files in the order that they need to be compiled (external js files that I use before my own files, etc.) And I also always test to see if I'm using the wrong '/' and I still can't consistently get external links to function properly. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Look at the console and network tab in your browser dev tools.

Comment: We can't really help you unless you give us some examples... But SLaks is right, the network tab in the dev tools will give you a lot more information on the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This most likely has to do with the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

The easiest alternative here would be to use something like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or simply download the js files. If you want a truly interactive web development workflow, use Google Chrome's development tools with [workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces).

It'll allow you to live edit js/css files on the fly and see the changes as you make them. This is really good for someone still trying to learn the ropes as it'll give you constant feedback.